# How do you overwrite user CSS?

Tags: css

If a user has a default style-sheet, how do you reset all the CSS?

Comment: What do you mean by "user"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a CSS reset at http://cssreset.com/scripts/eric-meyer-reset-css/.  It will reset the user stylesheet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!

Answer (score 1):

you can add `!important`to all your settings, like

```
body {
 background: none !important;
 font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

Still, if the user styles also have that !important setting added, your's will probably be ignored)

(P.S.: But why would you want that?)